# Using Azure AD users as Service Credentials on on-premises Windows Server

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

Is it possible credentials from Azure AD to configure a Service on Windows? This account would also access a SQL Server instance on another machine and run commands. 
Assuming there's no on-premises Active Directory installed on this environment, but there should be clients consuming this application.

Is this strange scenario viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use an Azure AD account to run a service account on windows. The only way you could achieve something like this is to implement Azure AD Domain Services and join that machine to that domain, then you would have access to the users created in Azure AD.

That said, you really don't want to run a service as an end users account, it is going to be affected by things like password expiry, MFA etc.